# How to use iron-selectable correctly? Items appear to be null when used like iron-pages

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have a fairly simple Polymer element which implements `IronSelectableBehavior`but I find that `this.items` is always an empty array.

I have it setup the same way `iron-pages` is, simply with child elements and not much else:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selectable.html">
<dom-module id="test">
    <template>
        <style>
        </style>
        <div id="container">
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    (function(root) {
        'use strict';

        Polymer({
            is: 'test',

            behaviors: [Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior],

            observers: [
                '_selectedChanged(selected)'
            ],

            _selectedChanged: function(val, prev) {
                var self = this,
                    selected = this._valueToItem(val);

                if(!selected) {
                    throw val.toString() + ' not found.';
                }
            }
        });
    })(window);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

With the following example:

```
<test attr-for-selected="data-test" selected="{{selected}}">
    <div data-test="one"></div>
    <div data-test="two"></div>
</test>
```

When `_selectedChanged` is called, `selected` is `undefined` because `this.items` is an empty array.

`iron-pages` is setup with even less code than this but somehow works, so I'm unsure what is wrong here.

Comment: You can try `iron-selector`. It selects items too they way you want it.

Comment: @JJJ if you figured out how to solve your problem, could you add the working example as an answer. You have a good question and it would be helpful to see the solution.

Comment: Added a brief explanation as to why this happens, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is fairly simple:

- `iron-selectable` sets `this.items` to the content nodes after attachment
- It does this by observing `selected` and populating `this.items` if they are not already

This causes issues if you want to interact with `this.items` in your own `selected` observer, simply because the array is not yet populated by the time your observer is executed.

To get around this, listen on the `iron-select` event which is guaranteed to execute *after* the `iron-selectable` observer.

If you need to know the previous value (because `iron-select` doesn't get it passed), set it in a `selected` observer and read it in your event listener.